# How can I fix an issue in IE where borders don't show up when the mouse isn't hovered over an image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, image

I am trying to create a rather simple effect on a set of images.  When an image doesn't have the mouse over it, I'd like it to have a simple, gray border.  When it does have an image over it, I'd like it to have a different, "selected", border.

The following CSS works great in Firefox:

```css
.myImage a img
{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 3px;
}
.myImage a:hover img
{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

However, in IE, borders do not appear when the mouse isn't hovered over the image.  My Google-fu tells me there is a bug in IE that is causing this problem.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to locate a way to fix that bug.

Comment: Can you post some HTML so we can see the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different colour.  I'm not sure IE understands 'grey' (instead, use 'gray').

Answer (score 1):

The following works in IE7, IE6, and FF3.  The key was to use a:link:hover.  IE6 turned the A element into a block element which is why I added the float stuff to shrink-wrap the contents.

Note that it's in Standards mode.  Dont' know what would happen in quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      a, a:visited, a:link, a *, a:visited *, a:link * { border: 0; }
      .myImage a
      {
          float: left;
          clear: both;
          border: 0;
          margin: 3px;
          padding: 1px;
      }
      .myImage a:link:hover
      {
          float: left;
          clear: both;
          border: 3px solid blue;
          padding: 1px;
          margin: 0;
          display:block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="myImage"><a href="#"><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"></a></div>
    <div class="myImage"><a href="#"><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"></a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience IE doesn't work well with pseudo-classes.  I think the most universal way to handle this is to use Javascript to apply the CSS class to the element.

CSS:

```css
.standard_border
{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 3px;
}
.hover_border
{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Inline Javascript:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" class="standard_border" onmouseover="this.className='hover_border'" onmouseout="this.className='standard_border'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

IE has problems with the :hover pseudo-class on anything other than anchor elements so you need to change the element the hover is affecting to the anchor itself.  So, if you added a class like "image" to your anchor and altered your markup to something like this:

```
<div class="myImage"><a href="..." class="image"><img .../></a></div>
```

You could then alter your CSS to look like this:

```css
.myImage a.image
{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 3px;
}
.myImage a.image:hover
{
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Which should mimic the desired effect by placing the border on the anchor instead of the image.  Just as a note, you may need something like the following in your CSS to eliminate the image's default border:

```css
.myImage a img {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *background* instead of the *border*.

It is not the same but it works in IE (take a look at the menu on my site: [www.monex-finance.net](http://www.monex-finance.net/ENG/index.php)).

Comment: This is a great suggestion and doing this (which works) helped me figure out the real issue (my color name).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

put that in your header, should fix some of the ie bugs.